# Laravel getting data from a database

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to get data from a database using the code ( in my controller)

```
public function viewStock()
    {
        $stocks = Stocks::where('ID', '=', 2);
        if($stocks->count())
        {
            $stocks = $stocks->first();
            return View::make('trucks')
                ->with('stocks', $stocks);
        }

    }
```

For some reason it goes through with the IF statement then outputs NULL on my output page which contains the code :

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
<p>{{ var_dump($stocks->stockcontent) }}</p>
@stop
```

I guess it doesnt count anything as it returns NULL however it still goes through with the if statement?

**EDIT** 
When i use `var_dump($stocks)`
it prints : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzoZi.png

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$stocks`? Why do you have `Stocks::where('ID', '=', 2)` and `$stocks->first()`, is `ID` not a primary key?

Comment: Yeah it is a primary key, and if i dont put $stocks->first() in it gives this error : http://i.imgur.com/Sbv4CSU.png , ive also tried other columns.

Comment: Yes, you need to use eloquent more elegantly -- `$stock = Stocks::findOrFail(2)` will do what you're trying to do. If you want to manually check what it contains, you can do `$stock = Stocks::find(2)` and check what it contains. Also I'd advice you install laralvel debugbar, that way you can see what is returned in your queries or even dump data to session and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're never issuing the query. So, when you do `$stocks->count()`, you're actually sending a `COUNT()` as your `SELECT` clause. This is how you should do it:

```
public function viewStock() {
    try {
        $stocks = Stocks::findOrFail(2);

        return View::make('trucks')
                   ->with('stocks', $stocks);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // Handle model not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed it, I dont know if there are any other ways of solving it but my fix was because when I had first inserted data into the databse i didnt have the default created_at and updated_at that laravel generates and when I used a script to put some data in it automatically added these fields and whenever I tried to print the data that had the created_at and updated_at filled, it worked.